# "Page section" or "page sections"?

Tags: word-choice

I'm developing a web application and there's a menu for the user to add and edit content. It is called *Page Content*. *Page Content* has a category which let the user select where the content for the will be placed.

I'm not sure if I should name the category *Page Section* (the category is about choosing a page section) or Page Sections (the category has many page sections).

Some examples of the labels of the menu:

name: Sections

singular_name: Section

add_new_item: Add New Section

edit_item: Edit Section

new_item: New Section'

search_items: Search Section

not_found: No Sections found

all_items: 'All Sections' ),

(is the usage of singular and plural right in the examples above?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you want "Search Sections", but the others look all right.

It depends on how you search:

Search Section = seach within one section
Search Sections = search among all sections
Search for Section = search for a specific section
Search for Sections = search for a set of sections among all sections